# ANR Input dispatching timed out in android application

Tags: android

I am getting input dispatching timed out ANR in my android application, but could not get trace it. Any one knows what's happening:

```
Input dispatching timed out


Sample attributes:
motorola malta (moto e(7))
Android 10 (SDK 29)
Version: 30 (3.9)
Occurred: 3 hours ago
Enhanced
Plain text
Expand allexpand_more

Thread 1
"main" tid=1 NativeMain threadIdle
Your app encountered an ANR, but the stack trace captured does not show the problem
#00  pc 0x000000000005a7d0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (syscall+28)
#01  pc 0x00000000000e44e5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+80)  
#02  pc 0x0000000000416dc1  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::GoToRunnable(art::Thread*) (.llvm.12369370306581232504)+324)  
#03  pc 0x0000000000416c55  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::JniMethodEnd(unsigned int, art::Thread*)+8)  
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native method)  
at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:336)  
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:174)  
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7386)  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)  
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:492)  
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:980)
```

Above is the stack trace of ANR. Is there any hint,g guess or what should I do?